# Take specific data from database with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

Hello i have some routes and i am receiving data from database

```
   router.get('/', expressAsyncHandler(async (req,res) => {
            const products = await Product.find({})
            res.json(products)
   }))
```

With this route i get all the products from mongoDB

I want to get all products with the same category so i begin to try a new route

```
   router.get('/roundBall', expressAsyncHandler(async (req,res) => {
            const products = await Product.find({})
            const roundball= products._category == 'Rounded'
            res.json(products)
   }))
```

But it's not working, in my local host i am getting false in the screen. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, all the products are getting retrieved from mongoDB. Then the attempt to filter by category in node.js is incorrect.

One way to fix the problem is to correct how the filtering is done at node.js side:

`roundball` should be created by using [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), this way.

```
        const roundball= products.filter( product => product._category === 'Rounded')
```

However, it will be more efficient to query mongoDB only for products corresponding to the desired category:

```
        const roundball = await Product.find({_category: 'Rounded'})
```

This way, less data needs to transit between mongodb and node.js.

Comment: I follow the recommendations, but my only problem is that it's returning an empty json array

Comment: Could the field "_category" be actually spelled "category"? in the data, is "Rounded" capitalized?

Comment: yeah my bad, your answer is correct. Thanks you!

Answer (score -1):

products._category == 'Rounded' is a comparasion so it will always return true of false. What you need to do is map over the elements and compare each element's category with 'Rounded'.